# Spring gives 500 error when trying to intercept url pattern (role prefix error?)

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm getting this when trying to reach /test URL as unlogged:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Filter execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot.setDefaultRolePrefix(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot(DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java:31)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot(DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java:17)
    org.springframework.security.access.expression.AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.createEvaluationContext(AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.java:47)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:33)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
    org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    etc.
```

My spring spring-config.xml file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/profilepage**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/test**" access="ROLE_USER" />


        <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessdenied" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" 
            login-processing-url="/authorize"
            default-target-url="/profile"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?logout" logout-url="/logout"/>

        <csrf />
    </http>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from users where username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username, ROLE from user_roles where username = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

 <beans:bean id="encoder" 
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
  </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

It does not any difference when intercept-url pattern is `/test` or `/test/**` or `hasRole('ROLE_USER')` and `hasRole('USER')`. It works only if .jsp filename is the same as pattern - but in that case it makes everything useless when I try to reach the page as unauthorized user because having something like that in my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showprofilePage(Model model, Principal principal) {

            String username = principal.getName();
            //do smth
            return "user/profilepage";

        }
```

Spring blocks access at return moment, not when making request.
This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>prospr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProSpr</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Draft-16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <path>/prospr</path>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>password</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>

  <systemPropertyVariables>
   <java.util.logging.config.file>
   src/test/logging.properties
   </java.util.logging.config.file>
  </systemPropertyVariables>

            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

I'm using Tomcat as you can see.

Comment: I guess you have to set pattern as `pattern="/profile**"`

Comment: It does not matter if it's "/profile" or "/profile**" or even "/profile*". Always the same error.

Comment: full stack trace please

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JAwHw15U

Comment: is this error occurs for some specific role  or user?

Comment: No. It happens even when `permitAll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your Maven pom looking correct it appears you have the incorrect version of `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` on your classpath. Specifically it appears you have spring-security-web-3.x.jar on your classpath instead of spring-security-web-4.x.jar.

Please ensure you run a clean build. This could also happen if you have multiple versions of spring-security-web. If you have a war file you can view the content to see what version of Spring Security is inside it. You should also look in any parent classloaders (i.e. /lib). For additional information on its classloaders and locations to search refer to [Tomcat Docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

Comment: I have checked war and it's totally messy. It consists both 4.x and 3.x versions of spring dependencies I used before. I forgot tu use "clean" and probably maven has old jars in his cache or smth and was copying them when packaging all the time. Thanks.